Upper bound on a definite integral
This is from a Courant Comprehensive Exam in the $70$'s:
$\mbox{Prove that the integral}\int_{3}^{5}\sqrt{x^{2} + 4}\,\,{\rm d}x < 10.$
Please solve this.

What did you try? Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions. This is a PSQ.

The function $y=\sqrt{x^2+4}$ is concave up since $y''=\frac4{(x^2+4)^{3/2}}>0.$ So, the area of the trapezoid $ABCD$ where $A=(3,0), B=(5,0), C=(5,\sqrt{29}), D=(3,\sqrt{13})$ is greater than the area under the curve and above $x$-axis.
$$\int_3^5\sqrt{x^2+4}\,dx<(ABCD)=\frac{\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{29}}{2}\times(5-3)=\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{29}<9<10.$$

I find one way, but not so succinct, here is my idea:
$\sqrt{x^2+4}\leq x+c$, where $c$ is a constant. Then I get $c^2+6c-4\geq0.$
So, I choose $c=\sqrt{13}-3,$ then $\int_{3}^{5}(x+c)dx=8+2(\sqrt{13}-3)<10$
